# Disappearing Gameobject in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a word game in Unity in which I have many GameObjects. Each GameObject name is a letter from A to Z.

When I click on the object, the letter appears on screen. When I have made a word, it compares it to a dictionary to see whether it is correct or not. I want that when I made a correct word from the letters and click the button, the GameObject containig those letters from which I made the word disappears.

Here is the code:

```c#
internal void ReadStudent(string filetoread,string tableName, string itemToSelect, string wCol, string wPar, string wValue){

    //jsScript = Camera.main.GetComponent<chk1>();

    string connection = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" + filetoread;
    Debug.Log(connection);
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT word FROM "+ tableName + " WHERE " + wCol + " " + wPar + " '" + wValue + "'";

    OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(connection);
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery,con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("dic");


    try{
        con.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        //text = dt.Rows[3][1].ToString();
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }

    finally{
        if (con.State!=ConnectionState.Closed){
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Dispose();
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count>0){
        text = dt.Rows[0]["word"].ToString();
        Debug.Log(text);
        Debug.Log (wValue);
        Debug.Log ("Correct");
        for(int i=0; i<=wValue.Length;i++){
            Debug.Log ("Enter");
            if(wValue[i]==gameObject.name[i]){
                Debug.Log ("Enter");
                gameObject.SetActive (false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`GameObject.Destroy(gameObject)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) should do the trick.

Comment: in my game the gameObject is creating on run time with name like A(Clone) GameObject.Destroy.(gameObject) is not working for it. how can i get the gameObject creating on Runtime

Comment: I mean yeah, the gameObject has to be a reference to the object you want to destroy. When you create the object, you should at that point have a reference to it, maybe you could store them in a list and then go through and delete them later? Kinda depends on how everything is laid out

Comment: maybe gameObject.setActive(false); is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the game object you can use `Destroy (gameObject)`, or while I wouldn't suggest it `DestroyImmediate(gameObject)`.

Otherwise, a more efficient method is to deactivate it and then reactivate it when necessary using `gameObject.SetActive(false);`

And remember when I say game `gameObject` I mean a GameObject variable equal to the game object to destroy, for example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//You need to assign it in the Start() or from the editor
public GameObject A;

public class ActiveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        //to deactivate it
        A.SetActive(false);

        //to activate it
        A.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

If you were to use gameObject, you would end up deleting/deactivating the gameObject that is executing your script.

Hope you found this useful,

Alex